# iOS: Create Raw Transaction in swift

Tags: web3j, ios

I'm working on a project related to blockchain and need to figure out, how raw transaction can be possible, I got no reference for this as of now. Can anyone help me? I have tried this lib: https://github.com/matterinc/web3swift

but unable to get the exact thing?
Please Help me

Answer (score -1):

You also can use [EthereumKit](https://github.com/yuzushioh/EthereumKit) and [ContractSwift](https://github.com/daisuke310vvv/ContractSwift)